# Coherent DMA memory on ARM

Tags: caching, memory-management, arm

I'm new to ARM/Linux and there are things that aren't clear to me. ( I might be completely off on this)
I'm trying to get a coherent mem allocated for my device driver (i.e, a region that is non-cached or write-through).

So I attempt to do that with *dma_alloc_coherent* in Linux.
When I inspect the page table attributes, I notice that I get "Shareable device" memory type.
There are a few memory types regarding the cache policy as in the link below:

http://infocenter.arm.com/help/index.jsp?topic=/com.arm.doc.ddi0363e/Cacgehgd.html

I was expecting that I would get a non-cacheable or a write-through memory. What is the cache policy of the"Shareable Device" type?? and how does it differ from explicit non-cacheable and write-through memory types??

Answer (score 0):

Actually depending on the ARM architecture release is possible that cached memory regions are coherent after DMA transfers. There is an extension in the AMBA spec (AXI Coherent Extensions) that keeps the coherence of caches memories after another master has performed a transfer, in other words, that after another core or DMA performs a transfer, your cache will have the updated values (or at least the tags are marked as invalid).

It means that, if the kernel of linux is aware of your ARM architecture release it trusts on the coherency mechanism to update caches and thus the pages are marked as shareable.

Please see the issue D of the ACE Protocol Specification on ARM site (registration required) for more information.